# Flatten iterator of two dimensional array in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, iterator, kotlin

I have a `Grid` class which is wrapper over 2d array of `Cell` objects. I would like this class to implement `Iterable<Cell>` interface in order to use it in loops and iterate directly overall cells. Is there a simple way to do that? Does Kotlin support `yield return` style iterators? My current solution is quite verbose:

```
override fun iterator() = object : Iterator<Cell> {
    val currentOuter = grid.iterator() // grid is object of Array<Array<Cell>>
    var currentInner = if (currentOuter.hasNext()) currentOuter.next().iterator() else arrayOf<Cell>().iterator()

    override fun next(): Cell {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw NoSuchElementException()
        }

        return if (currentInner.hasNext()) {
            currentInner.next()
        } else {
            currentInner = currentOuter.next().iterator()
            currentInner.next()
        }
    }

    override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
        return currentInner.hasNext() || currentOuter.hasNext()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple solution would be something like this:

```
val grid: Array<Array<Cell>> = ...

override fun iterator() : Iterator<Cell> = grid.flatMap { it.asList() }.iterator()
```

Comment: Or even just `grid.asSequence().flatten()`, which returns a [`Sequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sequences.html) instead of an `Iterator`, which is useful for example if you then want to run `.map { foo(it) }.first { bar(it) }`. An `Iterator` will map _all_ the elements before finding the `first`, whereas a `Sequence` will map "lazily".

Answer (score 5):

> Does Kotlin support yield return style iterators?

Yes, it does, through the feature of coroutines. Here's a self-contained example:

```
data class Cell(val d: Int)

val grid: Array<Array<Cell>> = arrayOf(arrayOf(Cell(1), Cell(2)), arrayOf(Cell(3), Cell(4)))

fun cellSequence() = buildSequence {
    grid.forEach { it.forEach { yield(it) } }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    cellSequence().forEach { println(it) }
}
```

Although this particular problem could have been simply solved with just a `flatMap`, the presented code can serve as a template to write any kind of procedural-looking code, for example:

```
fun complexCellSequence() = buildSequence {
    yield(Cell(-1))
    if (grid.size <= 2) {
        yield(Cell(2))
    }
    for (row in grid) {
        if (row.contains(Cell(1))) {
            yield(Cell(1))
        } else {
            yield(Cell(12))
            row.forEach { yield(it) }
        }
    }
}
```

This would be quite nontrivial to rewrite without coroutines.